# Hello, do you sell this/these? - When referring to something, should we use it or them?

Tags: difference, pronouns

**Example 1**

If I go to a store and ask the employee whether they have a certain product, with me pointing at the picture of the product or maybe holding one, which one should I use to ask a question like below?

> Hello, do you sell this/these?

**Example 2**

If my friend and I are talking about a certain thing and I find it interesting that the people in my friend's town sell it, which one should I use to ask a question like below?

> Wow, you guys sell that/those?

**Example 3**

I am making some descriptions about an apple so that the listener can guess what I am talking about. Which one do I use?

(1)

> This is a round object. You can see it every day in your life. It is a kind of fruit.

(2)

> They are round objects. You can see them every day in your life. They are a kind of fruit.

Comment: either one would work, for all three questions. There might be a slight preference for one, depending on the individual circumstances (eg what is being sold, why you are describing apples)

Answer (score 0):

It really depends what you are talking about.

Were they small round fruits "these" would seem appropriate and idiomatic as it would for biscuits, buns, courgettes, tomatoes, quiches, etc.

If it was a brand of breakfast cereal, yoghurt, wine, salad dressing, or the Radio Times. I would use "this".

There may be products where either would seem alright such as bottled beer, or a type of fruit drink.

Answer (score 0):

Both options are grammatically correct, for all three Examples provided by you, depending on the number of objects. If you're talking about a singular object (like a brand name, a type of object, etc.) then "this" should be used. If you're talking about something of which more than one item is sold (fruits, t-shirts, souvenirs, etc.) then "these" is idiomatic.